# Why does this CSS3 Animation happen instantly?

Tags: css, animation

I'm having issues with this CSS3 animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hide_card {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes hide_card {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes hide_card {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes hide_card {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
  }
}
```

Here's the element:

```
.activity .card.invisible {
  width: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: hide_card;
  -moz-animation-name: hide_card;
  animation-name: hide_card;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1; 
}
```

In my Javascript, I am adding the `invisible` class using JQuery, and the element becomes hidden (and the class is added in the inspector), but it does it instantly without animating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can supply more information as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the animation rules to the card before it gets the `.invisible` class. so it would look something like this I guess:

```
.activity .card {
  transition: all 1s ease 1s;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-width: 3px;
}

.activity .card.invisible {
  width: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0; 
}
```

I used the shorthand and omitted vendor prefixes...